# Cannot login to my drupal site because of php version 5.6

Tags: users

I have installed drupal 7.36 and developed my site on localhost in XAMPP. After I logget out I'm not able to log in again even if name and password is correct. I have only one user created - admin. After I attempt to log in I get a message

> You are not authorized to access this page.

I can still log in. I have tried every solution I found on Internet:

- Log in with another browsers
- Clear all cookies of browser
- Clear all caches
- Truncate all cache_ tables, truncate sessions and flood tables
- Set `$cookie_domain = 'localhost'` variable in settings.php
- Add `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '127.0.0.1')` to settings.php
- Restart apache server
- Create another user programatically and log in as new user
- Log in programatically
- Vacuum/reindex database in pgAdmin

Nothing worked for me. It's really simple drupal website. What exactly could cause this problem?

I've reinstalled my site (and lost my database data) and enabled again my theme and all the modules. I was able to log in and log out, repeatedly. But then I logged out one more time and closed the browser. After reopening the browser, I was not able to log in again, even with other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I found that the problem is with php version 5.6 and workaround is:

```
function aikidolm_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  $_SESSION['aikidolm']['ulogged'] = 1; 
}
```

https://www.drupal.org/node/2363219#comment-9366567